# Why aren't my tasks staying in the queue after an error in gcloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

As far as I can remember, when an exception occurs during the processing of a task in a task queue, the task stays in the queue and begins retrying. For some reason, none of my tasks are staying in the queue after an error hits. Any ideas of where I can troubleshoot?

Comment: If your task handler catches the exception and returns 200 then Google tasks will think the task completed successfully.  Did you check the return code?

Comment: Yeah, I am catching all exceptions and returning error code 500. I can see the exceptions in the logs with the 500 return values as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview#appe), for Cloud Tasks queues with App Engine targets, if a different response from 200-299 or no response is sent, the task is retried.

Check your queue current parameters running this command in the Cloud Shell: `gcloud tasks queues describe [QUEUE_ID]`.If the retry parameters are not configured according to your needs, you can find how to change them in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#retry).

If this is properly configured, make sure that your failing tasks are not having a 200-299 status code which would take them out of the queue.